# deinit not called on child viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a parent viewController that is inserting a childVC with a class method in the childVC. This works great.

```
class func insertIntoController(parentController: UIViewController, parentView: UIView) -> VideoDoorbellLiveView? {
    guard let liveViewController = parentController.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(liveViewIdentifier) as? VideoDoorbellLiveView else { return nil }

    liveViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    parentController.addChildViewController(liveViewController)
    parentView.addSubview(liveViewController.view)

    let views = ["view": liveViewController.view]
    var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[view]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: views)
    constraints.appendContentsOf(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[view]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: views))
    parentView.addConstraints(constraints)

    liveViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(parentController)

    return liveViewController
}
```

The parent makes sure that a controller is there and sets a couple of String variables, etc. Works beautifully.

```
    guard let controller = VideoDoorbellLiveView.insertIntoController(self, parentView: liveView) else { return }
    liveViewController = controller // liveViewController is an optional instance variable
```

My problem is when the parentVC goes away (the deinit *is* called), the child VC deinit is *not* called.

Any ideas why?  There is no reference of the parentVC in the childVC.

I even tried to do this in the parentVC without guaranteed success:

```
deinit {
    if let liveViewController = liveViewController {
        liveViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
}
```

Comment: There's probably a retain cycle in the child VC

Comment: That was my first thought. Checked every closure and we are doing a [weak self] every time. Not sure what else to look for :(

Comment: Use Instruments. If there's a leak, it will pinpoint it.

Comment: Also I'm a little worried about your `liveViewController = controller`. You should not be keeping a second persistent reference to your child view controller. You already have one (in the `childViewControllers` array) and that is the only way you should be accessing your children. At the very least, make this reference weak, but it would be better not to have it at all.

Comment: @matt That recent reference was in an effort to deal with the child VC not going away. Also, since the parentVC is calling its deinit, then I should be able to assume it's instance variable also goes away.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had a retain cycle and needed to pass weak self to firebase observer in parent view controller, then deinit was called on both:

```
    func observeFeatureChanged(){
    microbeRef.queryOrdered(byChild: Nodes.TIMESTAMP)
        .observe(.childChanged) { [weak self] (dataSnapshot) in
            if let featureDic = dataSnapshot.value as? [String: Any]{
                let featureName = dataSnapshot.key
                if let index = self?.featureNames.firstIndex(of: featureName){
                    self?.featureNames[index] = featureName
                    self?.featureDictionaries[index] = featureDic
                    let indexpath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
                    self?.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexpath], with: .automatic)
                }
            }
    }
}
```